# How can I use a vtkFollower with a PNG image source?

Tags: vtk

I've been searching through the vtk documentation but I cannot see how I can use a PNG image with a vtkFollower.

In order to do so, I seem to need to obtain a vtkMapper with the image data. However, there does not seem to be a mapper for this purpose (i.e. loading of images).

How can I get a vtkFollower of type image?

Note: vtkFollower.SetMapper expects vtkMapper. Since vtkImageMapper does not inherit from vtkMapper, using vtkImageMapper is not possible.

Comment: Did you get that working with `-p` attribute? The MySQL one?

Comment: No, I managed to uninstall/reinstall completely somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use PNG reader and pass it to texture.

Then, In vtkfollower object "settexture" should be called.

Please refer to links below.

https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/PNGReader

https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/TextureMapPlane

https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/Follower